# Custom Instant BSON Format in ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, bson, reactivemongo

In ReactiveMongo, a default java.time.Instant bson format is provided in the DefaultBSONHandlers class.

I have a trait in which I define my custom format for Instant (toEpochMilliSafe is an extension method for Instant):

```
trait BSONFormat {
  implicit object InstantWriter extends BSONWriter[Instant] {
    override def writeTry(t: Instant): Try[BSONValue] = Try(BSONDateTime(t.toEpochMilliSafe))
  }
}
```

Then I create a BSONDocument in a class that inherits from BSONFormat:

```
BSONDocument(AlertSchedulesSchema.timedTriggerTime -> BSONDocument("$gte" -> from)
```

But the serialization of 'from' to bson uses DefaultBSONHandlers implemention instead of mine.
Is there a way to force it to use my implementation?

Comment: How do you know that it is using the `DefaultBSONHandlers ` instead of yours ?

Comment: @sarveshseri I call it with value of "from = Instant.MIN" and get "long overflow" exception, with a call stack showing it went though the formatter at the DefaultBSONHandlers class. I need my implementation because it deals differently with Instant values outside of the bson date range.

Comment: You need to make sure that according the implicit resolution rules your implicit (typeclass instance) is the one resolve/with the top most priority (nothing specific to ReactiveMongo there).

Comment: @cchantep can you assist? How to make my implicit take precedence over DefaultBSONHandlers when creating the BSONDocument as above?